# ReactJs: browse state element with map, TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I'm actually learning reacts. and I meet this error when I try to loop over my DB, so to fix the problem I try to create an array and add some information in, but the problem is already there, can anyone help me please ?

this is the code:

```
class Toto extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: {
                zappy_server: {
                    project_name: "Zappy Server",
                    project_description: "description",
                    src: "https://www.iphon.fr/app/uploads/2019/09/test-photo-iphone-11-pro-austin-mann-0.jpg",
                },
                my_teams: {
                    project_name: "My teams",
                    project_description: "description",
                    src: "https://www.iphon.fr/app/uploads/2019/09/test-photo-iphone-11-pro-austin-mann-0.jpg",
                },
                shell42: {
                    project_name: "42Sh",
                    project_description: "description",
                    src: "https://www.iphon.fr/app/uploads/2019/09/test-photo-iphone-11-pro-austin-mann-0.jpg",
                },
                trade: {
                    project_name: "Trade",
                    project_description: "description",
                    src: "https://www.iphon.fr/app/uploads/2019/09/test-photo-iphone-11-pro-austin-mann-0.jpg",
                },
            },
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
        })
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <Carousel className="caro">
                {this.items.map(item => (
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img
                            className="img-size"
                            src={item.src}
                            alt="Third slide"
                        />
                        <Carousel.Caption>
                            <h3>{item.project_name}</h3>
                            <p>{item.project_description}</p>
                        </Carousel.Caption>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                ))}
            </Carousel>
        )
    }
}
export default Toto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your items are an object not an array. Change `items: { ...}` to `items: [...]`.

Also you access state via `this.state.items`.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping is done with array and as I see your state field item is an object.
Simply change the code to:

```
class Toto extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [
                {
                    project_name: "Zappy Server",
                    project_description: "description",
                    src: "https://www.iphon.fr/app/uploads/2019/09/test-photo-iphone-11-pro-austin-mann-0.jpg",
                },
                {
                    project_name: "My teams",
                    project_description: "description",
                    src: "https://www.iphon.fr/app/uploads/2019/09/test-photo-iphone-11-pro-austin-mann-0.jpg",
                },
                {
                    project_name: "42Sh",
                    project_description: "description",
                    src: "https://www.iphon.fr/app/uploads/2019/09/test-photo-iphone-11-pro-austin-mann-0.jpg",
                },
                {
                    project_name: "Trade",
                    project_description: "description",
                    src: "https://www.iphon.fr/app/uploads/2019/09/test-photo-iphone-11-pro-austin-mann-0.jpg",
                },
            ],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
        })
    }
    render () {
      let {items} = this.state
          return (
            <Carousel className="caro">
                {items.map(item => (
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img
                            className="img-size"
                            src={item.src}
                            alt="Third slide"
                        />
                        <Carousel.Caption>
                            <h3>{item.project_name}</h3>
                            <p>{item.project_description}</p>
                        </Carousel.Caption>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                ))}
            </Carousel>
        )
    }
}
export default Toto
```